# How to automate Android unit tests without using ADB in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have created Android unit tests project. They need ADB running for the tests to run successfully.
I have also used the command line tool of Android Debug Bridge for unit testing the Android Unit tests projects.
In above both the cases ADB needs to be running.

Is it possible to run the tests without running ADB. This will be useful for build systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the errors then you have to use ADB to get the errors.